# Migrate entire WhatsApp from iPhone 6 to Android

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-transfer, ios, device-migration

I'm looking to migrate my WhatsApp from iPhone to Android, including media (not just chat). I know that it is not possible via native WhatsApp features. I don't want to use a third-party app (not reliable, sensitive & private data).

Is there a way to do it manually somehow? Even if it is conversation-by-conversation (including the media). I mean, it is about putting the right files at the right place at one point. Is there a way to do this manually?

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not to restore chat history (which is easy) but to restore medias, maybe manually, without third party app

Comment: there is a WhatsApp folder on the phone you can copy to PC